# How can I calculate the sum of the numbers of two columns for only a portion of the rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have an Excel sheet with 10,000 rows and two columns. All 20,000 cells are filled with numbers and there is no missing data. I want to have a third column, the values of which are the sum of Column A and Column B. For example, C70 = A70 + B70, and C82 = A82 + 82, and the like.

The only problem is I want to do it for only a portion of the rows, say from row 125 to row 8954. I don't care about the rest of the values. And I don't want to do it by dragging the grid using the mouse. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to show each individual line or do you want the total of all those lines in one cell?

Comment: I believe [`SumProduct()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) will be your friend for this, assuming 1 final value..

Comment: @ScottCraner I need each individual line.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks, but I don't want one final value. I need all individual sums.

Comment: So...  `=A2+B2` in cell `C2`?  What is the hang-up related to your portion of rows?  What is the logic?  If this is related to VBA, please post what you've tried thusfar.

Comment: Implement a test for row with an if statement in the first cell. Double click the pointer in the cell to automatically fill the rest of the column with the formula

Comment: @Cyril Yes. But for all rows from 125 till 8954.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to SEQUENCE() (Currently only available to Office 365 Insiders) then yes it is possible:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(1000,,ROW(),1))+INDEX(B:B,SEQUENCE(1000,,ROW(),1))
```

Where `1000` is the number of rows desired.  Place the formula in the first cell desired and it will automatically fill the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need some logic about what is going on, related to the start and end row.

You can use an `if-statement` or `sumifs()` for this... will do an if-statement so i can specify not meeting the requirements as null.

With Start row as 2 and end row as 4 (see image), you can use this formula, and drag it down to the bottom of all columns:

```
 =IF(AND(ROW(A2)<=F$2,ROW(A2)>=E$2),SUM(A2:B2),"")
```

[image]

Notice in the image that C5 has no value; this is due to the conditions of the if-statement being false.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is the dragging part! I don't want to drag, as I have, say, 25000 rows!

Comment: You don't have to drag when your other columns have values. Double click the pointer!

Comment: @Gordafarid then use Fill Down from the Home tab.  You can also just double click the lower right corner of the cell in which the first formula is found

Comment: @JvdV If I do that,  it goes all the way down to the very last row. I don't want that. I want this to be applied to, say, row 24 untill row 12387, out of 1,000,000 rows. Without dragging. Is that possible?

Comment: Or use a simple VBA macro

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, a simple macro that will do what you want by asking the user what the starting and end row is.

```
    Sub test()
    Dim startrow As Integer 'variable to hold first row
    Dim endrow As Integer 'variable to hold last row

    startrow = InputBox("Enter the start row")
    endrow = InputBox("Enter the end row")

    'loops through you desired range calculating what you want
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = startrow To endrow
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next

    End Sub
```

Just change the values to suit your needs in what cells you want to add up and where you want the sum to go.